# Select Tag with Bootstrap shows doubled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a page styled with bootstrap, when I added a select tag it shows doubled, and on chrome I see elements that I don't have in my HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
       <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en">      <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/all-ie-only.css" />
  <![endif]-->
    <title>Command Central &bull; <cfoutput>#PageTitle#</cfoutput></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,     maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE10">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1bac6ec7f7.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--- Custom CSS --->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/custom-vertical.css" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/all-ie-only.css" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change Screen</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Result:**
[image: Doubled Select]

**Chrome Dev Tool:**

[image: Chrome dev Tool]

Please any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the complete code? For I try analyze, because I used your code in firefox and worked properly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  


 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE10">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1bac6ec7f7.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--- Custom CSS --->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/custom-vertical.css" />

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Modal Body -->

 <div class="modal-body">

      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change Screen</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is complete code, I mean I can't paste whole page because it has a lot of backend staff too. but the problem is select tag. whenever I put this tag it shows me doubled

Comment: But your code was missing <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>                                ...       and .... </body>
</html>                                                      Can you use the code that I post?

Comment: Updated question, and also check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/gj9axc18/5/ this one has two select menu's too,  but HTML on jsfiddle has one select tag

Comment: You need the `class="selectpicker"` ? Because it that was created the second select menu's.

Comment: No I don't. even wih no class in select tag I have two select tags

Comment: I copied your code and still have two select tags ((((

Comment: OHH man I am sorry, Problem was that I used Materialize cdn, because I moved from materialize to bootstrap and forgot to remove link to materialze CDN from footer.
I use separate header and footer for the page and didn't look at the footer. My bad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's ok, no problem. I was happy per you.